# workmanager periodic request not working without setting a flex period

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have a unique periodic reques that runs without error when i set a flex period.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(EarthquakeUpdateWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES).setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES).addTag(PERIODIC_WORK_KEY).setConstraints(constraints).build();
            WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context);
            workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(PERIODIC_WORK_KEY, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
```

However if i remove the flex period eg.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(EarthquakeUpdateWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES).addTag(PERIODIC_WORK_KEY).setConstraints(constraints).build();
            WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context);
            workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(PERIODIC_WORK_KEY, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
```

I get an error like this

```
Didn't find WorkSpec for id 475c853c-09b8-4d38-9074-0b373f60c1b7
```

Any ideas on how to fix this or what is going on ?

Comment: Where are you getting the error message? What makes you think that is related to your work not being enqueued?

Comment: this only happens when i remove the flex period on a periodic request. This error shows up in logcat:`2020-08-12 18:12:17.421 24103-24134/com.example.earthquakeclone E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Didn't find WorkSpec for id 5868efe7-671d-466e-981e-95c5846e9040`

Comment: That may just mean it is being picked up to run immediately. What makes you think your work isn't running?